# Umbraco with Windsor Castle error after adding nuPickers plugin

Tags: plugins, umbraco, castle-windsor, embedded-resource

With an existing Umbraco site running fine we added the nuPickers plugin which does not seem to like Castle. In the browser console we are seeing a lot of 404 / 500 errors being generated for the embedded resources within the plugin. (The plugin is a single DLL with css and js files embedded in it.)

The site continues running fine (back and front ends), except for the plugin.

The Event log is showing: "No component for supporting the service nuPickers.EmbeddedResourceController was found"

We have tried route.ignoreroute in our route config, and also adding a handler in web.config, both unsuccessfully, as we do not think the resource requests should be getting to castle?

Any help or pointers gratefully accepted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone comes across this ticket, we 'solved' this by

1. Getting all of the embedded resources, (html, js & css - not the classes)
2. Physically placing them inside the App_plugins folder in the correct structure (as they were being requested),
3. Renaming the js and css files (by adding the .nu after the file
   extension), and,
4. Adding the following mime types into the web.config

```
      mimeMap fileExtension=".css.nu" mimeType="text/css"
      mimeMap fileExtension=".js.nu" mimeType="application/javascript"
```

Then, everything seems to work - but there MUST be a better solution, surely?